# How to delete ADUser using Python pyad module

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyad

I'm having a problem with deleting ADUser.

```
pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server="dc1.domain.com", username="service_account", password="mypassword")

user = aduser.ADUser.from_dn("cn=myuser, ou=staff, dc=domain, dc=com")

user.delete()
```

Unfortunately I could not figure out how to format this text to look like a real traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Automation/qa/robot2/python_lib/keywords/AD/unittest.py", line 34, 
    in <module>
    ad_connect.bg_ad_user_remove(user_login='vasya.oconnor@test-acme.com',dn_string= dn_string)
  File "C:\Automation\qa\robot2\python_lib\keywords\AD\_bg_ad_general.py", line 156, in bg_ad_user_remove
    user.delete()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyad\adobject.py", line 537, in delete
    if not parent:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\future\types\newobject.py", line 90, in __nonzero__
    return type(self).__len__(self)
AttributeError: type object 'ADContainer' has no attribute '__len__'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Tell us what have you tried to solve your problem. Questions that show research effort are more likely to be answered

Comment: Please paste the complete error message (and don't try to type it).

Comment: @Burhan Khalid added traceback as you asked.